# Feature-request: Not allowing [homework] as the only tag to a post

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Is it possible to make it so that the site will not accept a post that has [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) as the only tag to the post? I know that this problem only comes up rarely (as discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/using-homework-tag-by-itself), but if we can automatically require that some other tag be added, it might help.

Comment: Is it possible for someone with some basic SQL knowledge to write a query on data.SE for finding such posts? (There has been a data dump last week, so it is going to be pretty up to date)

Comment: @Arturo: I think this feature request was essentially declined by Jeff Atwood in his answer on the other linked page.  Specifically he says: "There is no provision in the engine for forcing another tag when a certain tag is selected, and I think this would end up being a crutch to allow meta-tags anyway (or worse, a stealth way of implementing pseudo-hierarchies in tags), so I would be against it."

Comment: @Eric: Hrmph. I think you're right. Of course, that was some months ago, so things may have changed (just like the "identifying un-accepted answers" was declined at the time as essentially not possible given in the engine, but now is sort-of implemented [though not very well, as far as I can tell]).

Comment: I've tried to make the query at data.SE: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/59833/ The query return 36 results. Data are updated once a month, so this might be out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned before, there really is no provision for this that wouldn't be a bizarre, contorted workaround.

If it truly comes up rarely, as you stated, perhaps human handling is adequate in this case?

If it becomes some kind of epidemic, we can revisit it.